# Can pulling a door fast create air movement that causes heart pain, maybe considering weather pressure of 1035 hPa? How does it work?

Tags: pressure, air

Flatmate has a habit of using all his strength to open the door of his room, which is on the adjoining corner of mine. I feel like each time the air is pulled. Now it's winter, air pressure 1035 hPa outside, (my room's door is closed). I feel my heart is pulled, at the moment. I don't think it's just a feeling, because just after, there's a pain in my heart.

Is there a way pulling a door creates as much air movement as that? And for that air movement to cause a pain in your heart? If there is, how does that work? What is the scientific explanation?

Comment: It sounds like you should be consulting a medical doctor.

Comment: I did, the doctor said my heart is okay. But I feel heart pain when they pull their door. (So I don't have a proof yet.)